# Java installation failed

Tags: java

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 on flash memory due to corrupted hard drive that could hardly keep OS. Usually when computer get down because of empty battery or other reason it is reinstalled, the Ubuntu on temp memory and I have to reinstall everything again, like skype, plugins for firefox, etc.

However I usually need a few basic things like adobe plugin and generally didn't need java and I use ubuntu for about a half and year in this way (ok, i used to have also windows on computer for other things but now I don't) so lately I actually found out I cannot use some chatroom sites, probably thats the biggest issue.

And I really don't get how things are done with java. I had some trouble at beginning with the adobe plugin but at some point I got how it is done and made a 'habit' but with the java installation - I am struggling.

I tried in two different ways, one with the soft manager and other in terminal directly but non worked. I would be glad if you could guide me and give me instructions on how to do it with my Ubuntu on flash memory.

Its not a big deal but it irritates me. I will appreciate your help.

And happy new year everyone :))

Comment: Is it a flash drive or an SSD?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using Ubuntu as live mode with your flash drive,
First of all you need to make your Ubuntu bootable flash drive with "reserved space" for store your extra installation of software and user files!

[When starting up from your flash drive , documents, extra installed software, plug-in and settings will be stored in reserved extra space, more over you can select how much space for allowcating for this purpose when you making a bootable flash drive]

[image: Ubuntu Live USB reserved space screen shot]

Comment: thanks but I dont see how this has anything in common with my java problems. not to mention that my CD is not working and I dont have reserve flash drives so I dont want to experiment with my only available memory option. since ubuntu is working right now. if I was looking for expensive and risky options I would rather buy a new hard drive and have as much "reserved space" as I want to

Comment: "Reserved space" only need for Live USB drive, regular hard drive do not need this steps!

Comment: Of course, that was irony